# Why does defining a callback function inside a function with the api call throw an "Uncaught ReferenceError"?

Tags: javascript, api, scope, callback

I am working on a simple cross-domain JSONP API call. In the first code, the callback function **displayWeather** is defined inside the function **findWeather**. This gives the *"Uncaught ReferenceError ..... displayWeather is not defined"* error. The second code works. I am not able to figure out why the first case doesn't work. Any explanation will be much appreciated. Thanks. 
EDIT: I am wondering if this has something to do with scoping? and/or scoping combined with api call?

```
  function findWeather(lat, lon) {

  var weatherApi = document.createElement("script");

  function displayWeather(weather) {
    document.getElementById("cityCountry").innerHTML = "City: "+weather.name;
  }

  weatherApi.type = "text/javascript";
  weatherApi.src = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&appid=137bbb43f4df58953838eefe6b9c3044&callback=displayWeather";
  document.head.appendChild(weatherApi);

}
```

The second code below works

```
function displayWeather(weather) {
    document.getElementById("cityCountry").innerHTML = "City: "+weather.name;
  }

function findWeather(lat, lon) {

  var weatherApi = document.createElement("script");

  weatherApi.type = "text/javascript";
  weatherApi.src = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&appid=137bbb43f4df58953838eefe6b9c3044&callback=displayWeather";
  document.head.appendChild(weatherApi);

}
```

Comment: You are right about scope. `displayWeather` is not available in the global scope, only exist in `findWeather` function scope.

Comment: Cool thanks. Can you please add this as an answer? THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayWeather` is not available in the global scope, only exist in `findWeather` function scope.